# Swift "Ambiguous use of operator '=='"

Tags: compiler-errors, operator-overloading, swift

I'm trying to compare an instance of `UIUserNotificationType`, which is a `RawOptionSet`, to some value:

```
var types: UIUserNotificationType = ...
if types == UIUserNotificationType.None { // <-- Error here
     ...
}
```

But am getting an error on the second line:

> Ambiguous use of operator '=='

Any ideas about where this might come from?

(I could do `types.toRaw() == 0`, but I think it'is quite ugly...)

---

`UIUserNotificationType` declaration for reference:

```
struct UIUserNotificationType : RawOptionSet {
    init(_ value: UInt)
    var value: UInt
    static var None: UIUserNotificationType { get }
    static var Badge: UIUserNotificationType { get }
    static var Sound: UIUserNotificationType { get }
    static var Alert: UIUserNotificationType { get }
}
```

Comment: what about `types.value == UIUserNotificationType.None.value` it none the less feels like a bug to me since UIUserNotificationType is Equatable

Comment: I am not familiar with this yet. So I will put this here as a suggestion first. I think you should be using optional binding  `if let someType = types.None) {
    // do something with someType
}`

Comment: @markhunte Thanks for the suggestion, it does not work though. `types` is no Optional apparently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead, whilst I try to see what's wrong with yours (this works) :

```
    var types = UIUserNotificationType.Sound | UIUserNotificationType.Badge

    switch types {
        case UIUserNotificationType.None:
            println("None")
        case UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound :
            println("Badge & Sound") // This will print
        case UIUserNotificationType.Badge:
            println("Badge")
        case UIUserNotificationType.Alert:
            println("Alert")
        case UIUserNotificationType.Sound:
            println("Sound")
        default:
            println("default")
    }
```

this also works, but it does seem like a bug that the original doesn't :

```
if types.value == UIUserNotificationType.None.value {
        println("None, too")
}
```

Comment: How does this behave if the `RawOptionSet` has multiple values? i.e. `let types = UIUserNotificationType.Badge | .Sound`.